# unable to determine capabilities of user properly

Tags: moodle

I am having a bit of a problem checking capabilities of a given user. I am trying to change a user's icon based on their capability - namely having the ability to rate a forum post.  The system permissions seem to be set up correctly which is puzzling.  When I go into the system as admin and check the capabilities overview, I can see that a student cannot rate a forum post but a teacher can. 
[image]

so in order to change the icon based on that, I do:

```
    if (!$this->courseid){
        $context = context_user::instance($this->user->id, IGNORE_MISSING);    
    }else{
        $context = context_course::instance($this->courseid, MUST_EXIST);
    }

    if (has_capability('mod/forum:rate', $context, $this->user->id)){
        $filename = 'instructor';
    }else{
         $filename = 'student';
    }
```

but everyone is getting the student image.  What could it be that I am missing?  I also thought of checking the role(s) but that isnt working either.  Anyone run into this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for the **'mod/forum:rate'** capability, you need to provide the context object of type **context_module**:

```
// $cmid = id from course_modules table
$context = context_module::instance($cmid, MUST_EXIST);

if (has_capability('mod/forum:rate', $context, $userid)){
    $filename = 'instructor';
}else{
     $filename = 'student';
}
```

Another way to check for student / teacher roles in a course (This assumes that the students are not allowed to edit or update the course):

```
$context = context_course::instance($courseid, MUST_EXIST);
if(has_capability ('moodle/course:update', $context, $userid)) {
    // Teacher
    $filename = 'instructor';
}
else {
    // Student
    $filename = 'student';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your response but I guess I am kind of hung up on the whole Context thing:  I agree with the permission that you are using, but I dont understand how the context relates to any of this.  I am sure that either of these snippets of code would work if I were using the correct context.

Comment: Moodle docs: https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Context Each capability has just one context type. If you need to know which context type to use for a specific capability, you could check the `capabilities` table in the database. In that table each capability has a `contextlevel`, a constant that could be one of the following: `10` (CONTEXT_SYSTEM), `30` (CONTEXT_USER), `40` (CONTEXT_COURSECAT), `50` (CONTEXT_COURSE), `70` (CONTEXT_MODULE) or `80` (CONTEXT_BLOCK). So for capability `mod/forum:rate` you would check the `capabilities` table, it has `contextlevel=70` so we use context_module for it.

Comment: Sorry but I should have mentioned that this is being run when the user is logging into the system(/moodle/lib/outputcomponents.php), before any course has been selected, etc. so if I am understanding this correctly, neither of these permissions would be good to use because each course has its own forum which would be a seperate content id, correct(I hope)?

Comment: in other words, not some permission that is course-specific but rather something that is on the system level

Comment: By default student and teacher roles cannot be assigned at the system level, only for a specific course. One way to work around this would be to check if the user has a teacher role in at least one course. You could do it like `$isTeacher = $DB->get_field_sql("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM {role_assignments} WHERE userid=? AND roleid IN (SELECT id FROM {role} WHERE shortname=?)", array($userid, 'editingteacher'));`

Comment: Thanks Adrian - you really helped me understand what is going on... I really appreciate your help!